# Need help writing a mongo API query in Javascript(React) that needs info from multiple levels

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, nosql

So I have a collection called "contributors." Within that collection the objects look like this:

{

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5ef1f75f7e6fb579ed3e5e8a"),
"@attributes" : {
    "cand_name" : "name",
    "cid" : "",
    "cycle" : "",
    "origin" : "",
    "source" : "",
    "notice" : ""
},
"contributor" : [ 
    {
        "@attributes" : {
            "org_name" : "National Beer Wholesalers Assn",
            "total" : "20000",
            "pacs" : "20000",
            "indivs" : "0"
        }
    }, 
    {
        "@attributes" : {
            "org_name" : "Alabama Power",
            "total" : "15000",
            "pacs" : "10000",
            "indivs" : "5000"
        }
    },
```

... with 10 "@attributes" objects in the "contributor" array.

What I need to do is query this whole collection to find each cand_name object that includes a certain org_name, which I'm already uncertain of how to do *(since every time I've tried to query with a string it replaces the spaces in my string with %20)*.

But then I need to display a table with all the cand_name objects that included that org_name with the total, pacs, and indivs numbers that correspond to that cand_name & org_name.

To be super clear here I'm trying to make a table that displays every politician that a company has given money to *(and how much)*.

So through all this I'm looking in multiple levels of each object and need to display data from all those levels together in one table. I may just be overthinking this, but it seems like it's going to be a complicated query...

**Help?**

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out! Ended up working with the backend guy on our project and he did it all on backend.